# Why does brace around variable fail on my server's PHP but not my local's?

Tags: php, syntax

I have the following code within some code i wrote:

```
  foreach ($appfields as $key => $field) {
    if (isset($app->{$field}) && isset($app->{$field}['und'][0]['value'])) {
      $node->{$contactfields[$key]}['und'][0]['value'] = $app->{$field}['und'][0]['value'];
    }
  }
```

i added an echo after the foreach with this:

```
$app->{$field}['und'][0]['value']
```

and on my staging server it prints nothing; but on my local dev machine it works correctly.

Has anyone ever come across this syntax not being supported? The staging server is running: PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.25

there is no error message generated; it simply doesn't evaluate the code correctly.

Comment: Seems to work fine in 5.5.9 in a quick reproduction https://3v4l.org/D0Hal (Add a line then do a quick preview to see a list of versions).  Dump out $app and make sure it contains what you think.

Comment: What's the PHP version on your dev machine? How do the error_reporting and display_errors config settings compare on the two machines? Is the data you're trying to `echo`the same in both cases?

Comment: Please add the output `var_dump()` `$app` and `$field` after your foreach to your question.

Comment: looking closer at $field within the loop and i can see a newline character at the end of each value; which messes up the object reference. Adding a trim($field) fixes my issue; but still odd that tis is not required on my devel machine.

Comment: Are you sure the newline is in `$field` on the dev machine?

Comment: No, the newline isn't in $field on dev machine.. and it shouldnt be on stage either. The code is the same and the db that the data comes from is the same. The $appfields array has trimmed strings only added to it.

Answer (score 0):

found my mistake.. oops... $appfields items had newline characters at the end. The server was linux, which cared, the dev machine was Windows, which didn't care. I added trim() in function which builds $appfields and now it works on both machines. Thank you for the hints.